# Is it possible to read data from CLI using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to read data from CLI using Selenium Webdriver. Actually I have started one service through CLI so just want to confirm if the service has been started or not?

Comment: No; Selenium is only a library to interact with a web browser. But you can use Java (or most other languages) to do so.

Comment: I am using Java, is there any option to read the data from CLI?

Comment: There are many options. What have you researched? What have you tried? Start by reading [ask].

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. Selenium establishes a connection to a browser, and only a browser.

However, depending on how you are using selenium (python? ruby? java? javascript? cucumber? robot framework?), it might be possible to use that language during your test to get information from the underlying OS.